RobotEyes library with new headless mode in selenium - redact argument not finding element properly
It seems that in chrome 128 new headless mode became default and I'm having problems with redacting elements with RobotEyes library.
Capture Full Screen     name=shareContactsSection        redact=['${footer}']

${footer} is searching for element with data-testid attribute
screenshot
It helps if I change headless in old mode add_argument("--headless=old") but probably this will become deprecated at some point?
I also get this notification when running in new headless mode
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
.....Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#58 is a dynamic-sized tensor).

Anyone else experiencing this problem?
expected to redact footer
expected result
actual: redact at wrong place
actual
